# Some questions about OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, properties

I have an object called clock.

I have a method of said object called time.

If I used this.propertyName inside my time method, this will give the property to my clock object, right? But what if there is an if/else statement (within the time method itself), for example, which needs to run before
the value of the property can be assigned?

```
if(t.getHours() >= 12){
        this.ap = "AM";
    }else{
        this.ap = "PM";
    }
```

So, if I used a simple value like this.ap = "hi", this works fine. It gives the property to my object. If I have a statement like shown above, the property is undefined. What is the best way around this?

Also, another quick question since I'm only just starting to use my own objects. If I have an object with 3 separate methods, and I want to use a value in ALL methods that's been declared within 1 method, assigning it as a property of my object allows me to do this. Am I right?

So If I used var property = "" in one method, the only way to access this in my other methods is to return it. But setting the property to the object solves this? I realize I can experiment around with this but I'd rather just know the proper way.

Edit: Here's an example. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something. I can't seem to define properties from within a method.

```
var clock = {};

clock.test1 = "test 1.";

clock.time = function(){

    clock.test = "test 2."; 

    if(t.getHours() >= 12){
        clock.ap = "PM";
    }else{
        clock.ap = "AM";
    }

}

alert(clock.test1);  //success
alert(clock.test); //returns undefined
    alert(clock.ap);  //returns undefined
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code. The binding of `this` is kinda tricky in JavaScript. The usual solution is to add a property called `that` or `self` or something similar to your object and assign `this` to it when you create the object. That way you always have a reference to the object itself.

Comment: `=>` is a syntax error, it should be `>=`. What is the `t` in `t.getHours`? (And are you sure `getHours` isn't a function, to be called with `t.getHours()`?)

Comment: ^Thanks for pointing that out, I did indeed mean to type getHours as a function.

Comment: OK. With those things fixed it should work. That is, if `this.ap = "hi";` works and you put that if/else structure _in the same place_ then it will work too assuming `t` is in scope and is an object that has a `getHours()` method. For more help please show all of the function where the if/else appears, and show how you call that function.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you would need to actually call the `clock.time()` function before trying to use properties like `clock.test` and `clock.ap` that are created within that function - the function isn't going to run itself automatically. (And you still haven't explained what the `t` object is as in `t.getHours()` - where is that defined?)

Comment: t is the Date object. That's not the crux of my problem though. I can call the function then I have access to the property I have defined, I just thought I could assign a simple property to my object without having to run the function.

Comment: You _can_ assign simple properties to your object, you already do so for the `clock.test1` property. But any code _inside_ a function will not run until you call the function.

Comment: I see, so is it an unconventional way of doing things to want to use properties from one method within several other methods? Are the methods meant to be more standalone? My initial understanding was that I could quickly pass all info between methods in the same object. I think I'm missing a link here.

Comment: Yes, multiple methods (of the same object) can all access properties of that object. That is the conventional approach. The properties belong to the object, not the individual method. _But,_ if you _create_ properties in a method they don't exist until after the method has been called.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for answering my questions. I think I understand now. If I define some properties within a method, those aren't actually assigned to the object until the function is run. I was just misunderstanding something here. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to avoid problems with binding `this` is to do something like this:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.someProperty = "foo";

    self.someMethod() {
        self.someProperty = "bar";
    }
}

var anInstance = new MyObject();
console.log(anInstance.someProperty);      // foo
anInstance.someMethod();
console.log(anInstance.someProperty);      // bar
```

This avoids problems with `this` being something other than what you expected it to be, which can happen depending on how you call methods (using a method as a handler for some DOM event for example).

This example works by exploiting `closure`, which is a very important concept in Javascript that you should read up on (Google it).